# Append the output as new line in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, append

I have a log file `log .txt` which is having the data in below format

```
Name=abc Date=20140710
Name=xyz Date=20140715
Name=pqr Date=20140810  And so on
```

I am fetching the data based on today's date and appending it to a log file in new line

```
today=$(date --date "+1 week" +%Y%m%d)

grep $today log.txt $'\r' >> append_file.txt
```

But when I am running the script, it is giving me exception like

```
: No such file or directory
```

Also, in the `append_file.txt`, it is keeping the data as

```
log.txt:Name=abc Date=20140710
```

Ideally it should keep only the data i.e.

```
Name=abc Date=20140710
```

Actually, my end point objective is mail the content of `append_file.txt` and I want the data line wise...... like this

```
Name=abc Date=20140710
Name=mno Date=20140710
```

At present, it is mailing the data in single line `Name=abc Date=20140710 Name=mno Date=20140710`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: `-h` for `grep` will remove the filename, which you could have found out yourself with a simple `man grep`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `$'\r'`? That's probably what's causing the error, since `grep` will look for a file called `\r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output looks like:

```
log.txt:Name=abc Date=20140710
```

Because grep thinks that you're giving more than one file to work with.

The problem is `$'\r'` in this line:

```
grep $today log.txt $'\r' >> append_file.txt
```

Replace it  by:

```
grep $today log.txt >> append_file.txt
```

or if you need to insert `\r` at the end of each line:

```
grep $today log.txt | sed -e 's/$/\r/g' >> append_file.txt
```

Comment: Hey, Is there any way to delete a line from the `log.txt` by taking some string like `abc` as input.......

Comment: `Echo "Please enter the string :"` then in next line `read value`....... if `value` is present in `log.txt`..... it should remove that line.......

Comment: you can use `sed -i.bak '/abc/ d' log.txt` this command will delete any line containing `abc` but it will create log.txt.bak just in case you want to roll back

Comment: using variable `sed -i.back "/$string/ d" log.txt`